# Maybe we're all just pavement oil

Tags: knowledge, movies

I don't think it'll be a hard one, but hopefully it's fun     : )

> One is not unlike your home, albeit to some eyes, much darker.
>
> Another was abandoned and hidden, a shameful and suppressed existence.
> No girl deserves such a fate. Yet in the end her secret is known to all.
>
> A genus of air-breathing land snails, or more specifically: terrestrial pulmonate gastropod mollusks in the family Endodontidae. Or at least was...
>
> A series of buildings in which corpses are reduced to ash by fire. But somehow I'm cold too.
>
> One was nursed by a wolf. Such an animal, no wonder he killed his
> brother.
>
> The leader of a group of heroes that prevented an evil goddess from
> returning to the world. But regardless of his deeds, he's still only
> half as well as humanity's last hope.
>
> A city located in southern Tunisia. Home of the native Berber
> population and one particular well known individual.
>
> The last has been extensively studied by astronomers, leading it to be
> termed "arguably the next most important one in the sky after the Sun,
> but don't be led astray, it is no star, have the balls to look it up a bit
> more.

We are all the same, and yet none exist together. What are we and where do we come from?

If you're looking for a hint, maybe you should look at the title a bit closer...

Comment: Also I really wanted to set a good pattern into the puzzle but couldn't come up with something that didn't make it all ridiculously obscure, so if you have any ideas, feel free to comment or post in your answer!

Comment: Whew, done. Looks like I've got some movies to watch! :) Neat puzzle, by the way.

Comment: oh, nice! ......

Comment: @GordonK Btw, I hadn't originally put the movies tag (because to me that was part of the riddle - what are we and where do we come from) - umm, am I supposed to put it anyway?

Comment: I added the tag once the answer was almost complete so that it would be included in the monthly challenge.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are all:

> Planets in movies. "None exist together" since they are in different universes. Perhaps the title could read "Pavement Oil**s**", which would be an anagram of **Movie Planets**.

One is not unlike your home, albeit to some eyes, much darker.

> **Dark Planet**: The name the aliens give to Earth in [*Escape from Planet Earth*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_from_Planet_Earth)

Another was abandoned and hidden, a shameful and suppressed existence. No girl deserves such a fate. Yet in the end her secret is known to all.

> **Miranda**: The [planet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Firefly_planets_and_moons#Miranda) in [*Serentiy*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serenity_(film)), home of a failed experiment with sinister results.

A genus of air-breathing land snails, or more specifically: terrestrial pulmonate gastropod mollusks in the family Endodontidae. Or at least was...

> **Thermia**: A genus of [snail](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermia), and home world of [*Galaxy Quest's* Thermians](http://galaxyquest.wikia.com/wiki/Thermia)

A series of buildings in which corpses are reduced to ash by fire. But somehow I'm cold too.

> **Crematoria**: Plural of crematorium, and the [planet](http://riddick.wikia.com/wiki/Crematoria) with harsh temperatures from the Riddick universe. *Thanks to Gordon K for this one!*

One was nursed by a wolf. Such an animal, no wonder he killed his brother.

> **Romulus**: The [brother of Remus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Romulus_and_Remus), and home world to Star Trek's [Romulans](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Romulan). Romulus killed Remus, and the Romulans destroyed Vulcan (*thanks to Gordon K for Vulcan reference*).

The leader of a group of heroes that prevented an evil goddess from returning to the world. But regardless of his deeds, he's still only half as well as humanity's last hope.

> **Tanis**: The hero from [Dragonlance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Dragonlance_characters), and the planet from [*Pandorum*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pandorum)

A city located in southern Tunisia. Home of the native Berber population and one particular well known individual.

> **Tataouine**: The [city](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tataouine) is real, but I assume the well known individual is Star Wars' Anakin Skywalker (from the planet [Tatooine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tatooine)).

The last has been extensively studied by astronomers, leading it to be termed "arguably the next most important one in the sky after the Sun", but don't be led astray, it is no star, have the balls to look it up a bit more.

> **Vega**: A relatively nearby [star](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vega) and the moon where Dark Helmet instructs his minions to [comb the desert](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g3iFJpGJiug).

---

It appears most of the clues begin with a reference to a real-world interpretation, then hint at the fictional interpretation.

Comment: You're on the right track, You're also right about Tatouine and Romulus, Vega is partly correct. Keep at it, you'll start seeing a clearer pattern!

Comment: ***Movie Spoiler Alert*** In the first film of the latest Star Trek franchise a Romulan destroyed the planet Vulcan. Romulans and Vulcans are closely related races.

Comment: Look at Chronicles of Riddick for number 4 and Vega is a Moon in the film the OP hinted at.

Comment: Aaaagh! It came to me right when I saw Vega, but I dismissed it because I was considering a different pattern at that point.

Comment: It was Miranda and not Pandora because of the use of 'she' (The planet's name is a girl's name) - And I realized the very first one was ridiculously vague, it was supposed to be 'Dark Planet' from the movie Escape From planet Earth (Earth is the dark planet, but because it is named based on the opinion of Aliens) - The fact there is also a movie called 'Dark Planet' was supposed to help in finding it. but yeahh.....    Good Work!

Comment: @Spacemonkey, you do realise that Pandora was also a *she*?

Comment: @Peter Taylor, I was thinking the same thing. Pandora fit to me mainly *because* of "she", but Miranda fit "abandoned and hidden".

Comment: @PeterTaylor   oops, my bad, I was thinking 'Pandorum' - well like Roland said, the last part still fit Miranda better :P

Answer (score 0):

I think I have at least part of the answer:

> Constellations

One is not unlike your home, albeit to some eyes, much darker.

> Cepheus

Another was abandoned and hidden, a shameful and suppressed existence. No girl deserves such a fate. Yet in the end her secret is known to all.

> 

A genus of air-breathing land snails, or more specifically: terrestrial pulmonate gastropod mollusks in the family Endodontidae. Or at least was...

> Limax

A series of buildings in which corpses are reduced to ash by fire. But somehow I'm cold too.

> 

One was nursed by a wolf. Such an animal, no wonder he killed his brother.

> 

The leader of a group of heroes that prevented an evil goddess from returning to the world. But regardless of his deeds, he's still only half as well as humanity's last hope.

> 

A city located in southern Tunisia. Home of the native Berber population and one particular well known individual.

> 

The last has been extensively studied by astronomers, leading it to be termed "arguably the next most important one in the sky after the Sun, but don't be led astray, it is no star, have the balls to look it up a bit more.

> Vega

Comment: The answer isn't constellations, however your very last one is on the right track!